# Change Logo based on certain page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, graphical-logo

I have a site which is advertising different brands, so for each different brand I have a new page, as each brand has their own logo I want this to change based on the current page being viewed.  Is this something I can achieve with JavaScript?

Logo example:

```
<a href="/home" class="logo"><img src="images/header/logo.png?" width="62" height="53" alt="" /></a>
```

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't make sense to. Determine which logo to use using the same method as you determine what other content to put on the page.

Comment: I would agree with Quentin. If you're using PHP or some other back end language to write the pages, then just do it the same way. If you have all different files, then each file can be modified. You'd have to do that to add the script anyways. What are you trying to make easier by using a script?

Comment: Based on your dynamic ideas for brands, you can set your logo.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have HTML like this

```
<a href="/home" class="logo">
<img id="logo" src="images/header/logo.png?" width="62" height="53" alt="" />
</a>
```

In your javascript/jquery, first of all get current page

```
var urlParts = document.URL.split("/");
lastPart = urlParts[urlParts.length-1] == '' ? urlParts[urlParts.length-2] : urlParts[urlParts.length-1];
```

`lastPat` will contain last segment in url. For example, consider `http://google.com/account` and you will have account in `lastPart`.

This lastPart will contain current page/url part.
You can use this to change logo path

```
if(lastPrt == 'some_page_or_url_name') {
$("#logo").attr('src', 'path_to_image');
}
```

Try something like this.

Answer (score 0):

A simple CSS solution might work too. You could place a class in the body with the name of the brand and use CSS to serve up the logo image.

in css

```
.nike a.logo{
background-image:url('nike.png');
text-indent: -9999px;
}

.adidas a.logo{
background-image:url('adidas.png');
text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

Then in your HTML

```
<body class="nike">
<a href="" class="logo">Nike</a>
</body>
```

or

```
<body class="adidas">
<a href="" class="logo">Adidas</a>
</body>
```

Of course this would assume that you can dynamically put the brand name as a class into some tag before the logo (like the body tag or a container div) in which case you could also just dynamically name the image path in the code.